# could not find implicit value for parameter sparkSession

Tags: apache-spark, implicit

I have a notebook with code below that throws error of:

> could not find implicit value for parameter sparkSession

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession, Row, DataFrame}
import org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans

def createBalancedDataframe(df:DataFrame, reductionCount:Int)(implicit sparkSession:SparkSession) = {

    val kMeans = new KMeans().setK(reductionCount).setMaxIter(30)
    val kMeansModel = kMeans.fit(df)

    import sparkSession.implicits._
    kMeansModel.clusterCenters.toList.map(v => (v, 0)).toDF("features", "label")
  }

val balancedNonFraudDF = createBalancedDataframe(nonFraudDF, fraudCount.toInt)
```

Error:

```
Name: Compile Error
Message: <console>:82: error: could not find implicit value for parameter sparkSession: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
       val balancedNonFraudDF = createBalancedDataframe(nonFraudDF, fraudCount.toInt)
                                                       ^

StackTrace:
```

It would be greatly appreciated if anyone can offer any help, thank you very much in advance.

UPDATE:

Thanks to Reddy's input, after I changed it to

`val balancedNonFraudDF = createBalancedDataframe(nonFraudDF, fraudCount.toInt)(spark)`

I receive the following error:

```
Name: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Message: Field "features" does not exist.
Available fields: cc_num, trans_num, trans_time, category, merchant, amt, merch_lat, merch_long, distance, age, is_fraud
StackTrace: Available fields: cc_num, trans_num, trans_time, category, merchant, amt, merch_lat, merch_long, distance, age, is_fraud
  at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(StructType.scala:267)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(StructType.scala:267)
  at scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:128)
  at scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:59)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.apply(StructType.scala:266)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.util.SchemaUtils$.checkColumnType(SchemaUtils.scala:40)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeansParams$class.validateAndTransformSchema(KMeans.scala:93)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans.validateAndTransformSchema(KMeans.scala:254)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans.transformSchema(KMeans.scala:340)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage.transformSchema(Pipeline.scala:74)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans.fit(KMeans.scala:305)
  at createBalancedDataframe(<console>:45)
```

UPDATE2:

```
featureDF.printSchema
root
 |-- cc_num: long (nullable = true)
 |-- category: string (nullable = true)
 |-- merchant: string (nullable = true)
 |-- distance: double (nullable = true)
 |-- amt: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- age: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- is_fraud: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- category_indexed: double (nullable = false)
 |-- category_encoded: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- merchant_indexed: double (nullable = false)
 |-- merchant_encoded: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)

val fraudDF = featureDF
      .filter($"is_fraud" === 1)
      .withColumnRenamed("is_fraud", "label")
      .select("features", "label")

fraudDF.printSchema
root
 |-- cc_num: long (nullable = true)
 |-- trans_num: string (nullable = true)
 |-- trans_time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- category: string (nullable = true)
 |-- merchant: string (nullable = true)
 |-- amt: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- merch_lat: double (nullable = true)
 |-- merch_long: double (nullable = true)
 |-- distance: double (nullable = true)
 |-- age: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- is_fraud: integer (nullable = true)
```

Why feature is gone???

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have your SparkSession and is named spark

you can pass it explicitly this way

```
val balancedNonFraudDF = createBalancedDataframe(nonFraudDF, fraudCount.toInt)(spark)
```

or create an implicit reference (spark2 or any name) in the calling environment. Example:

```
implicit val spark2 = spark
//some calls
// others
val balancedNonFraudDF = createBalancedDataframe(nonFraudDF, fraudCount.toInt)
```

Comment: Available fields: cc_num, trans_num, trans_time, category, merchant, amt, merch_lat, merch_long, distance, age, is_fraud.
say, cc_num is features and trans_num is label, then you can do so by:
`toDF("cc_num", "trans_num").select($"cc_num" as "features", $"trans_num" as "label")

Comment: tracking back this

Comment: `featureDF.filter($"is_fraud" === 1)` - in this dataframe, see if all the `features` values are nulls. If so, that is why it got dropped.(I think)

Comment: Thank you, no, not null.

Comment: wait a min! `.select("features", "label")`  you only selected two columns,  How did you get to print `fraudDF.printSchema
root
 |-- cc_num: long (nullable = true)
 |-- trans_num: string (nullable = true)
 |-- trans_time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- category: string (nullable = true)
 |-- merchant: string (nullable = true)
 |-- amt: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- merch_lat: double (nullable = true)
 |-- merch_long: double (nullable = true)
 |-- distance: double (nullable = true)
 |-- age: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- is_fraud: integer (nullable = true)` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190100/discussion-between-mdivk-and-c-s-reddy-gadipally).